# plUpload only uploading one file to server - HTML4

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, plupload, html4

As it stands, my code works with HTML5 and Silverlight. However when I use Flash or HTML4, the upload form stalls. And when I check the uploaded directory, only the first file is uploaded.[image: Screenshot]

Here's my javascript for one of the uploaders:

```
$("#origShapeUploader").pluploadQueue({

runtimes: 'flash,html4',
url: 'upload.aspx?originals=yes', //with a query string of yes, the files being uploaded won't be given a prefix of 'MOD'
max_file_count: maxfiles,
filters: [
    { title: "Shape files", extensions: "shp,dbf,prj,shx"} //these are the only file types allowed
    ],
multi_selection: true,
flash_swf_url: '/javascript/plupload.flash.swf', //in case silverlight and html5 support doesn't exist
silverlight_xap_url: '/javascript/plupload.silverlight.xap', //silverlight browser extension


});
```

This is screaming server side handler issue to me, so here's my code for handling the upload, the MOD prefix is used in a different part of my program.

```
    if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
    {

    int chunk = Request["chunk"] != null ? int.Parse(Request["chunk"]) : 0;
    string fileName = Request["name"] != null ? Request["name"] : string.Empty;

    HttpPostedFile fileUpload = Request.Files[0];

    var uploadPath = Server.MapPath("~/uploaded-files");
    if (Request.QueryString["originals"] == "yes")
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, fileName), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
            fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploadPath, "MOD" + fileName), chunk == 0 ? FileMode.Create : FileMode.Append))
        {
            var buffer = new byte[fileUpload.InputStream.Length];
            fileUpload.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }


    }
```

}

Comment: I don't have access to the code (at a previous job), but if I remember it seemed to call the handler for each item in the multi-upload tool.  Is that the case you're seeing here, and in HTML 4 mode it's not uploading anything but the first item?

Comment: Yes it calls the handler for each file... I think I figured it out. I put a response.write for testing purposes in a random spot... and now it works??? I think the Flash/HTML4 look for a response of some type, and before it use to output nothing... so it'd sit there and wait. Now that I output HTML of some sort each time it hits the handler, it works?

Comment: That's not a very satisfying answer.  Try taking it out and see if it works without.  May have been a bad build somewhere?  I assume you tried rebuild once or twice to clean out old stuff?

Comment: You're right, it's not. However I tried removing my response.write it doesn't work without it. So it appears my theory on Flash/HTML looking for some type of output may be true.

Comment: Using some client tools, do you see a HTTP 200 Response from the server ?
Also, is your Response buffered (Response.Buffer=true) ? You may try to flush it then.

Comment: When I check with Chrome's Network utility (is that the proper name for it?). With HTML4/Flash, I receive an HTTP 200 response back from the first item, and then it stops after that. When I add a response.write() and output the number of Files (1) on my upload.aspx... all four come back with a 200 response and upload successfully. I tried adding Response.Buffer=true at the end of my Page_Load, however it doesn't make a difference. I assume this is a plUpload specific bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return at least something from the back-end - OK, DONE, or json confirmation of some kind. Some Flash players have a bug where they do not recognize request completion if no output was returned from server. As for HTML4, it's just how it works.